# Java way of mimicking postgreSQL sorting order of ORDER BY character

Tags: java, postgresql-9.3

In our Java code, we have two modes, each with a different way of filling a list of Strings: either via an SQL query or programatically.

The SQL query sorts the list by a simple ORDER BY on a column of type character. This order/this SQL query should remain unchanged.

To make the results of the two modes comparable, I'd like to use Java for sorting the list of the second mode exactly as the first. But it seems that SQL and Java have many differences in sorting order w.r.t. special characters.

Could you point me to a description of the sorting order definition of postgresql-x64-9.3, which I'm using? The mySQL reference is not much of a help.

Edit: I'm using the US locale

Comment: Write your own [`Comparator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [use it to sort the list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: Most databases sort depends on Locale, so no easy anser "what sort postgresql"

Comment: Of course. That's my plan. But my question is: what is the comparator that postgresql uses?

Comment: I'd say it's almost safe to assume "lexicographically".  Any other sort with regards to text makes little sense.  That said...it's incredibly unclear why you would want or need to do this.  Why can't you just use Postgres to sort your array back for you?

Comment: Why not use Postgres to sort the Java list? But then I would need to create a new table, fill it, and let SQL sort it - just for sorting a list. Java can sort lists. I just need to know how it should be done